# Calling close on a ShowDialog()'ed form doesn't stop the code from executing on that form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

So I have my main form which will open another form from a menu option:

```
mstages = new MaterialStages( ofd.FileName );
mstages.ShowDialog();
```

Then in this form it checks to see if a file path is valid, if it isn't and the user can't provide one, I want the form to close.

```
DirectoryInfo di = null;

if ( findDataFolder() )
   di = new DirectoryInfo( Program.dataPath );
else Close();

//rest of the function
```

I've looked and the findDataFolder() is functioning correctly returning true and false when it needs to and the else is getting executed on 'false' returns. But it doesn't close the form and continues on with the rest of the function causing errors because the DirectoryInfo doesn't have valid data.

How can I return to the main form and close this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close does not stop the processing.

Use Return after Close();

```
if ( findDataFolder() )
   di = new DirectoryInfo( Program.dataPath );
else
{
  this.Close();
  return;
}
```

Although you might want to consider restructuring your code a little:

```
if ( findDataFolder() )
{
   di = new DirectoryInfo( Program.dataPath );
   // finish processing
}
else
  this.Close();
```

or

```
if ( findDataFolder() )
   di = new DirectoryInfo( Program.dataPath );

if (di == null)
  this.Close();
else
{
  // finish processing
}
```

Ideally, you really want to return the results of the Dialog:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
// or 
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
// or
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.About;
// etc.
```

Comment: The return call only returns to the method that called this one. This other method loops through a list of things and sends em one by one to this method. So I just get a bunch of error messages.

Comment: hmm, now that I think about it, maybe refactoring it a bit would help. I'm checking a directory path (that will be the same everytime if it's correct) every time I call the function. I'll try moving that to another location

Comment: @Justen Then instead of Close, you should return a result of the findDataFolder and the caller of the method can determine whether or not to close the form.  The code you posted did not demonstrate what was happening behind the curtain, so I could only guess.

Comment: @Justen- That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: I moved the redundant code I was talking about to the first method called on the form load and combined with the Close(); return; it worked exactly how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not a good idea to validate something in form loading event if validation result may causes the current form to be close, instead you can declare a method in this form's class and call this to validate what you want before showing form and if validation was true then show the form.

something like this.

```
    var form2 = new Form2();
    if (form2.ValidateSomething())
    {
       form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The validation method in Form2

```
    internal bool ValidateSomething()
    {
        // Return result
    }
```

hope this help.